# Is it possible to add file into dmg image of application by linux?

Tags: linux, macos, disk-image

I have a dmg image, that has been built by [create dmg](https://github.com/create-dmg/create-dmg) on a real Mac.
There is a starting window with background, link to "Applications", title for Finder, and so on...
I would like to add just one config file into this dmg and save it without breaking anything there. And all this on Linux.

Is it possible?